# Why didn't Mycroft speak the truth in "The Final Problem"?

Tags: sherlock

I watched "The Final Problem" and I have the below queries:

When Mycroft told Sherlock about Eurus, why didn't he tell Sherlock the whole truth..specifically about Redbeard?

As we can see later in the episode, Sherlock gets to know the truth.

Why was Mycroft not able to see that Eurus was going to show Sherlock the truth, once the game began?

Comment: i have decreased queries. Now at-least I may get answer

Comment: It's still a little confusing...what do you mean by  "Not Speaking the truth". Perhaps you could explain further....are you asking about Redbeard?

Comment: Yes. I mean about Redbeard.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### Because he's still protecting Sherlock.

Mycroft has to reveal/confirm the *existence* of Eurus because he's trapped into admitting something Sherlock has worked out anyway.

But that doesn't mean he still wants Sherlock to know **everything** she's done.

Mycroft to Sherlock...

> "Memories can resurface; wounds can re-open. The roads we walk have demons beneath ... and yours have been waiting for a very long time. I never bullied you. I used – at discrete intervals – potential trigger words to update myself as to your mental condition. **I was looking after you**."

Remember, Mycroft doesn't know that Eurus has control of Sherrinford until after they are nearly killed by the 'patience grenade' and even once they are on Sherrinford and trapped in the 'game' he doesn't **know** Eurus' final intention...just that she's torturing all three of them...albeit, mostly Sherlock.

He might consider that the 'big reveal' is her plan but he's still trying to prevent Sherlock from harm as he's always done.

For all he knows they might get out of it without him having to tell Sherlock at all.